# comparision of strings with numbers, how does it work

Tags: c++

```
string a = "10";
string b = "20";
if(a>b)
  std::cout<<a;
else
  std::cout<<b;
```

The above code gives me correct output, but I don't know how? Can someone please explain me how strings with numbers are compared in this case.

Comment: Comparison between strings is done lexicographically. Meaning character by character left to right.

Comment: Try comparing `"100"` to `"99"` :)

Comment: yes, it is failing. it is comparing lexicographically as mentioned by @101010

Answer (score 8):

It works just like any string comparison:

The two strings are compared lexicographically, and since the character `'2'` comes after the character `'1'`, we have `"20" > "10"`.

Let's do another example, taken from the comments: Given `"100"` and `"99"`, we compare their first characters, see that `'9'` comes after `'1'`, and so we get `"99" > "100"`.